# Границы между текстурами Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d, 2d, текстура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть текстура которая стоит вплотную, которая в редакторе выглядит нормально, а в игре появляется линия. Как её убрать?

Comment: А если выключить антиалиасинг в Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality, проблема остаётся?

Comment: антиалиасинг и не был включен